# Dropdown Nav bar having automatic width of contents

Tags: css, navigation

I have a wordpress site with a basic CSS dropdown menu, and seems the contents of the ul ul are rather large. I have put the ul ul at a static width, but I would love to have the width be as long as the title at all times. Seems `width:auto` isn't working. Hoping a guru can hold my hand.

http://bit.ly/fC7zT7

Under Our Products

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When styling list menus, always style the A tag. **Don't style the LI tag** (other than `float`, when needed).

Also, add `display:block` you your menu A tags. You'll probably need to tweak your padding/margins a bit bit this will make them all the same width.

Comment: so just add `width:auto` to the a tags?

Comment: No, use "display:block" - this makes them take up 100% width of its CONTAINER.

Comment: Simple but genius solution - helped me out a lot too. Also, putting white-space: nowrap; on the a tag will help long menu items from breaking lines on its own.